# space above header in wordpress (not found in codes)

Tags: php, space

Space above header appears (it was not appearing before) , and I made inspect for it via browser I found that its code is

```
<html lang="en-US" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" 
 class="csstransforms csstransforms3d csstransitions js flexbox 
 canvas canvastext webgl no-touch geolocation postmessage websqldatabase
 indexeddb hashchange history draganddrop websockets rgba hsla    
 multiplebgs borderimage borderradius boxshadow textshadow opacity 
 cssanimations csscolumns cssgradients cssreflections csstransforms 
 csstransforms3d csstransitions fontface generatedcontent video audio 
 localstorage sessionstorage webworkers applicationcache svg inlinesvg 
 smil svgclippaths js" style="height: auto;"><!--<![endif]--><!--
```

and is betwen codes of header

and it takes `margin-top:32 px`

I edited header.php,but couldn't found it ,Also I tried to remove node in browser inspection  the entire page got disappeared,

Please help me

Comment: Put your header.php into a pastebin and then provide us with the link. We have nothing to go on.

Comment: this is the header.php 
http://pastebin.com/FqWEy2mC

and this is the site

http://emac.com.au/

Comment: First of all, go fix your HTML errors: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://emac.com.au/

Comment: which pages do i have to fix ?